# What should I look for in a head torch?

Tags: gear, camping, clothing, flashlights, electronic-gear

After my first wild camping experience, I found that my hand torch was really inefficient in the evening compared to other people's head torches - what are the features that make a good head torch?

Comment: For general information on handheld lights/torches, see this related question: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/what-characteristics-should-i-look-for-in-a-good-torch-flashlight